# Only one copy of the dynamic library is needed in memory at a time?

Tags: c, linux, dynamic

I read [the article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-dynamic-libraries/#dynamicloading) about dynamic library. And I could not understand the sentence below.

> For programs that require multiple libraries, shared libraries can
>   reduce the memory footprint of the program (both on disk and in memory
>   at run time). This is because multiple programs can use a shared
>   library simultaneously; therefore, only one copy of the library is
>   needed in memory at a time.

It is the duty of the `ld-linux.so` to do relocation process(load the dynamic library etc..).

How does the `ld-linux.so` know that the library needed have been loaded?

How do the programs share them?

What if the library has been updated? Does the newly started program load the new one or use the one which is resident in the memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this is not an answer to all your questions, it just answers the sharing part:

The trick is the virtual memory management. When a program or shared library is loaded into memory, its code is simply mapped into the virtual memory space of the process. Since it is mapped as a write protected memory region, the same memory pages can be mapped into any number of virtual memory address spaces. The only thing that the virtual memory manager needs to know, is which part of the file is 'backing' a page.

When multiple processes reference the same part, the virtual memory system will always load this part only once, because it remebers which memory pages are currently resident in memory.

Even in the case that one program using a shared lib terminates before another process using the same shared lib is started, the virtual memory manager will be able to avoid reloading the shared lib in most cases. This is because the memory pages containing the shared library will be marked as unused, but as long as the memory is not needed for some other purpose, the so called page cache remembers what the contents of the memory pages is. And when the shared library is reloaded, the VM simply looks up the memory pages that still contain the required code.

Comment: Thanks cmaster. I am still confused. How could the virtual memory manager know that the shared lib has been loaded? by name or?

Comment: Just by the information of file (afaik by the inode, not by its name or path) and offset of the data on disk backing a memory page. The pairs of inode and offset backing the different memory pages are held in searchable form inside the kernel (the page cache). So, when a process wants to map a region of a file into its address space, the page cache can be searched for a memory page containing the requested data. If such a page exists already, that page is simply mapped into the address space of the process, and no load from disk is necessary.